# AWS EKS cluster stops and starts without apparent reasons

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Currently, the only information that I have is that after 2 weeks of no issues and no new deployments.
Right now, whenever I/my team try to access the services in this cluster, they stop (503 error), then automatically start again.

I am pretty much a novice in AWS EKS. Any help is much appreciated.

**Update 1:**
Monitoring shows that in 06-26-2023 (10:00) the CPU usage spiked from an average of 40% to an average of 60%. Memory usage and disk space usage show no deviations.

Also, there are applications which do encounter exceptions, but to my best available knowledge, all of them do have exception handlers built-in and that these errors are not showing up on Newrelic at all.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more insights about the problem? Have you considered checking the resource usage (Memory, CPU, Storage) if any were maxed out? Are there any conditions that results to unhandled exceptions in your application that causes the app to crash?

Comment: Thanks, you may also want to share what are the types of worker nodes assigned to this cluster, how have you guys provisioned the cluster? Did you manually configured it? use Terraform? use EKSCTL? CDK?